# std::find failure in C++ with vector of strings

Tags: c++

I was writing a small program in C++ where the function  checks whether the given string is present in a vector of strings or not. Here is the code

```
std::vector<std::string> keywords {std::string("add_contact"),std::string("who"),std::string("block"),std::string("make_group"),std::string("send_images")}; // List of keywords defined in the grammar
bool search_Keyword(std::string keyword_text)
    {

        auto pos = std::find(keywords.begin() , keywords.end( ), keyword_text);
        return pos == keywords.end( );

    }
```

On debugging this code i found that there was an error with std::find saying Errors reading Characters of string. i am not able to understand where the code went wrong. Thanks for  the help in advance.

Comment: This code looks fine.

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Can you post a [mcve] that give you the error?

Comment: When found, search_Keyword() returns false.  Is that what you want?  There is probably a better function name ...

Comment: Where exactly is this error displayed? It doesn't sound like something that would be coming from this function. Have you tried using a debugger to see the actual contents of the string that is causing this error?

Comment: @SeanBurton That is exactly his problem - this is something that the debugger may say (e.g. due to things being optimized out or stepping before the opening brace of the function). But the debugger has no authority over the correctness of your program.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the debugger is telling you about being unable to read out the string. This may happen for various reasons (e.g. optimizations that mangled debug information, trying to read function arguments before entering the function body, bugs in the debugger) and is not necessarily indicative of a problem. Look at the program's output, inspect other places in the program with the debugger, and/or use a debug build to verify that your code is doing the correct things.

Answer (score 0):

The code you write is fine... the only thing that is suspect is that you return `false` if you find an item! A better solution is this:

```
bool isKeyword(const std::string& keyword_text) // <-- better name
{
    auto pos = std::find(keywords.begin() , keywords.end( ), keyword_text);
    return pos != keywords.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet i used to do exactly what you need, if you only need this for strings you can remove all the template stuff ( i needed it to be literal type agnostic ) :

```
template <typename T, typename X>
bool KeywordLookUp(std::vector<T> &vec, X toFind) 
{
    auto pos = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), toFind);
    if (pos == vec.end())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
```